# Git flow, merge staging and release back to main

Tags: git

In a project have `main`, `staging` and `release` branches.

From time to time we cherry-pick into `staging`, making `main` and `staging` out of sync.

Then release branch usually is just a merge of whatever we have in staging.

e.g.

```
main    A -- B -- C -- D -- E --F
                   \
staging ---------- (merge-S) (cherry-F)
                                     \
release ----------------------------(merge-R)
```

Now, I need to sync main and I need to choose:

- a. Merge release -> staging and then staging -> main.
- b. Or merge release directly to main.
- c. Keep release as it is, and only merge staging back to main.

All of them will work just fine. The problem I see when I choose b. is that in the next merge main->staging, git will include all the merge-R commits as if they were new commits to it.

Is there a recommended flow for this?

Comment: From the title I understand that you are following Git Flow ([1](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), [2](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), [3](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html)), what does it say about this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it has some similarities but not exactly. Apparently it never merges back the release branch. So, I think in my case it would translate to never merging release back to staging. (opt. c).

Comment: I think "git will include all the merge-R commits as if they were new commits to it"(b) is IMHO normal because you don't cut off its ancestor. Look at my answer there, please. I never used cherry-pick anymore.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237501/10489562